# Filtering JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to add filter option to my grid.I use Fixed Data Table.Here is simple filtering example with that grid.

https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/examples/old/FilterExample.js

This example filter the Json array only by first name.But I need to filter by all of the objects in JSON Array.
 For example may JSON array is here:

```
 {"id":7,"first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Hottie",
"country":"Sweden","salary":12000},

{"id":9,"first_name":"Mary","last_name":"Parah",
"country":"Argentina","salary":10000}
```

When I write "arah" to the general input filter value.I need to show both of the two elements of array.Because "id:7" first name (Sarah) and "id:9" last name (Parah) include my filter value ("arah").

If the country value of the another element of JSON array include "arah" I need to show that too.

So I need to filter the JSON array by all of the values it include.
What do you suggest?

Comment: you have bunch of json and you want to fetch required data from that json. is it right ?

Comment: Yes.I have one JSON array and I need to filter that JSON by my input filter value.

Comment: If we're talking about a lot of data, strongly consider filtering directly from the server instead.  Client-side filtering is faster only if you're dealing with limited amounts of data.  Alternatively, you could "index" the array by using the first letter to group results if you see yourself having to search the same data repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the filter prototype of the array. It will be something like this:

```
var arr = [ {"id":7,"first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Hottie",
"country":"Sweden","salary":12000}, {"id":9,"first_name":"Mary","last_name":"Parah","country":"Argentina","salary":10000}]


var runFilter = function(arr,searchKey) {

    var filterFn = function(obj) { 

      // Iterate the obj for each key. 
      for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "string" && obj[k].indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }
     }


      return arr.filter(filterFn);
    }

var filteredArr = runFilter(arr,'arah')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the filter function in line 45 of the example code. It is

```
return row['firstName'].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy.toLowerCase()) >= 0
```

If you want to look into every part of an Object, you can use a `for...in` loop:

```
for(var key in row){
    if((row[key] + "").indexOf(filterBy) > -1){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Replace line 45 with the code above and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Array#filter in combination with Array#some and a check of the type.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 7, "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": "Hottie", "country": "Sweden", "salary": 12000 }, { "id": 9, "first_name": "Mary", "last_name": "Parah", "country": "Argentina", "salary": 10000 }],
search = 'arah',
result = data.filter(function (a) {
    return Object.keys(a).some(function (k) {
        if (typeof a[k] === 'string' && ~a[k].indexOf(search)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof a[k] === 'number' && ~a[k] === search) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = [ {"id":7,"first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Hottie","country":"Sweden","salary":12000}, 
                  {"id":8,"first_name":"Mary","last_name":"Parah","country":"Argentina","salary":10000},
                  {"id":9,"first_name":"Gold","last_name":"sonam","country":"India","salary":15000}];
         var filterKey = 'arah';  
         function findJsonString(arr,filterKey){
               var result = [];           
               for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  var part1 = arr[i].first_name.indexOf(filterKey);
                  var part2 = arr[i].last_name.indexOf(filterKey);
                  // console.log(arr[i]);
                  // console.log(' part 1 : ' + part1 + ' part 2 : ' + part2);
                  if(part1 != -1 || part2 != -1)
                  {                          
                      result[+i] = arr[i]; 
                      // OR result.push(arr[i]);                        
                  }
               }
               return result;
         }         
         console.log(findJsonString(arr,filterKey));
      </script>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[Object { id=7, first_name="Sarah", last_name="Hottie", more...}, Object { id=8, first_name="Mary", last_name="Parah", more...}]
```